# RPC with promises for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, rpc, promise

Are there any RPC modules which work with promises?

On the server I have functions which return promises. I would like to expose them for browser clients to call over websockts or fallbacks. I found some RPC libraries for example dnode, but they expect a callback as parameter.

I would like something like this:

Server:

```
rpc.expose({
    timeout: function (time) {
        var d = Q.defer();
        setTimeout(function () {
            d.resolve();
        }, time);
        return d.promise;
    }
});
```

Client:

```
rpc.timeout(2000).then(function() {
    console.log('done');
});
```

Comment: Am I to understand you are looking for a way to perform a procedural return on an event based system?

Comment: Try looking into Promise.promisifyAll() - 
http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html

Answer (score 5):

I've written an RPC implementation called [Wildcard API](https://github.com/reframejs/wildcard-api#readme) that lets you do just that:

```js
// Node.js server

const { server } = require('@wildcard-api/server');

// We define a `timeout` function on the server
server.timeout = function({seconds}) {
  await sleep({seconds});
};

function sleep({seconds}) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000));
}
```

```js
// Browser

import { server } from '@wildcard-api/client';

(async () => {
  // Wildcard makes our `timeout` function available in the browser
  await server.timeout({seconds: 2});
  // 2 seconds later...
  console.log('done');
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/blob/master/examples/twisted/wamp/basic/rpc/slowsquare/backend.js) what you are looking for?

The "backend" of the example runs both in NodeJS and in browser. There is also a Python version.

The "frontend" of the example (see the complete [folder](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/wamp/basic/rpc/slowsquare)) also runs in NodesJS, browser and Python.

You can find some diagrams [here](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/twisted/wamp/basic#deployment-options).

This is based on [WAMP](http://wamp.ws/) [version 2](https://github.com/tavendo/WAMP/tree/master/spec), and uses [Autobahn](http://autobahn.ws/) as a WAMP router.

Disclaimer: I am original author of WAMP / Autobahn and work for Tavendo.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any RPC modules which work with promises?

I'm not sure whether it is exactly what you are looking for, but there is `ref_send` which is based on message passing (see also http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/D).

Implementations are [Waterken](http://waterken.sourceforge.net/web_send/#Q) and [Q.js](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/HEAD/ref_send.md).

---

You will also want to have a look at [Q-connection](https://github.com/kriskowal/q-connection), "*a JavaScript library for communicating asynchronously with remote objects using promises*".